# Fancybox flickers and won't go to next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

Very simple thumbnail version of Fancybox with the other images hidden with the "display: none" div, and it used to work until I changed the navigation in my own css that had nothing to do with fancybox whatsoever. But when I uploaded my html/css files to the server, I started getting flickers, glitches on the bottom of the images, can't hit the "next" arrow or close out of fancybox. This is happening in all browsers MAC/PC. Has anyone experienced this before?

Javascript:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    padding : '0',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    }
});});</script>
```

Between HEAD tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
        <a class="fancybox-thumb" class="fancybox-thumb" href="images/concepts.jpg"><img src="images/concepts.jpg"></a>
</div>

    <div class="hidden">
    <a title="MLB All-Team Design for Back-to-school products" class="fancybox-thumb" href="images/art/mlbconcept.jpg"><img src="images/art/mlbconcept.jpg" /></a>
```

I have 11 images that are in the "hidden" div. I'm not too experienced with Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: did you any CSS transition? check your general rules or try using specificity instead. Does this http://jsfiddle.net/tbw52oz2/ behave the same as you are experiencing?

Comment: Actually Grimbode from here was able to figure out that my css < a>'s were conflicting with Fancybox's css nav setting. "position: relative" to be exact, was causing the flickering and glitches.